# IIS reverse proxy not hitting the actual API

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I am building a new common Authentication module for my application. For this, I need to intercept requests coming to API layer, route to the common Authentication service and continue with regular flow only if Authentication service returned success. When invoking Authentication service, parameters are passed to it, via query string, based on which it returns true/false as response.

Flow of events:

1. Browser invokes http://localhost/SampleService/api/Home?param=data i.e Site1
2. Reverse proxy rule on Site1 makes the call go to Site2 which is http://localhost/ValidateAuthN
3. Site2 checks the value of param and returns a JSON response - true or false
4. Browser gets the response back.

I am using IIS as reverse proxy with url rewrite module and ARR configured. "Enable proxy setting" has been checked for ARR on root node in IIS. On API site in IIS, I have configured rewrite rule as below:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost/ValidateAuthN" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I see that the request is redirected to Authentication service with query strings values and the true/false response returned by Authentication service is received directly in calling application. However, request is not reaching the actual API layer for further processing. What I want is that at step 4 above, the request should go back to site1 with JSON response of true/false.

Please suggest what could I be missing in this configuration.

Comment: I couldn't understand your description clearly. Do you mean you have installed the auth module in the http://localhost/ValidateAuthN web application? It will firstly check the true or false and then call what api? I suggest you could post more details information about how your  auth module work and how it call the web api.

Comment: @BrandoZhang: I have added flow of events and some more details  on what happens in authn service

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need an exception rule for the reply? Your match rule `(.*)` catches everything, so the true/false reply might be getting re-routed itself?

Comment: I have checked the failed request logs and found that reply is not not getting re-routed